# Finding unit vectors which makes an angle 60 degrees with both {1, -1, 0} and {1, 0, -1}

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Find unit vectors which makes an angle 60 degrees with both vectors `{1, -1, 0}` and `{1, 0, -1}`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, the site for asking questions about how to use the software product *Mathematica*! I suggest the following: 1) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Is this in fact a question about how to use the software?  Your question is not posted in proper *Mathematica* code.  Perhaps math.stackexchange.com might be a better place to look.

Answer (score 2):

For instance:

```
Reduce[{Simplify[VectorAngle[{1, -1, 0}, {u, v, w}] ==
                 VectorAngle[{1, 0, -1}, {u, v, w}] == 60 °,
                    {u, v, w} ∈ Reals], Total[{u, v, w}^2] == 1},
                       {u, v, w}] /. Equal[a_, b_] :> Equal[a, FullSimplify[b]]
```

$$\left(u=0\land v=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land w=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\lor \left(u=\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}\land v=\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}}\land w=\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}}\right)$$